# I can't define "enum QgsComposerItem::ItemPositionMode " to UpperRight

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In order to create a new map layout with labels, I have to set in my code the position of the labels with *ItemPositionMode*, but it the parameter is not accepted:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt4 import Qt
from qgis.core import QgsComposerMap

municipios = QgsVectorLayer("C:\\ROUTE\\MUNICIPIOS.shp","Municipios","ogr")
reg = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
reg.addMapLayer(municipios)

maprenderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
c = QgsComposition(maprenderer)
c.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
layout = QgsComposerMap(c,1,1,1,1)#example
layout.label = QgsComposerLabel(c)
layout.label.setText("LAYOUT")
layout.label.adjustSizeToText()
layout.label.setFrameEnabled(True)
layout.label.setItemPosition(10, 20, 10, 10, UpperLeft)
layout.c.addItem(layout.label)
layout.output("ROUTE\\my_map.jpg", "jpg")
```

The error message is:

> QgsComposerItem.setItemPosition(float, float, float, float,
>   QgsComposerItem.ItemPositionMode itemPoint=QgsComposerItem.UpperLeft,
>   bool posIncludesFrame=False, int page=-1): argument 2 has unexpected
>   type 'str'

Comment: This code works in my QGIS 2.10. Somehow you passed `20` as a string to setItemPosition(). Also you need `QgsComposerItem.UpperLeft`.

Comment: I have used it as a enum.. that's right, QgsComposerItem.UpperLeft. I don't know why QGIS is complaining now, because it says "c" is not defined. It is a QgsComposition object, then, should be accepted as a parameter for QgsComposerMap...